# tethering iphone 6s and ubuntu 20.04 - not working

Tags: 20.04, iphone, tethering

I have iphone 6s and just installed ubuntu 20.04.
I can use internet if switch on wifi but USB tetering does not work.

tried this commend and restart PC : sudo apt install ipheth-utils libimobiledevice-dev libimobiledevice-utils

but it does not work.

what need to do?

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running iOS 14 on your 6S then this is the problem. Yes you need libimobliedevice and ipheth-utils, but iOS 14 introduced an incompatibility.  You can read about it in various forums eg:

- [Has the iOS14 tethering issue been resolved? - For Developers - OpenWrt Forum](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/has-the-ios14-tethering-issue-been-resolved/74949)
- [IOS14 USB tethering not working · Issue #1038 · libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice · GitHub](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/1038)

The Linux community have developed a workaround which has already been pushed into the latest kernels (I think all 5.10.x, but also some 5.9.x), but Ubuntu 20.04 is not using that latest kernel.

There is a Ubuntu utility called `mainline-gtk`, which lets you upgrade your Ubuntu kernel with just a few clicks.  I used it upgrade my Ubuntu 20.04 kernel from 5.4.0-58 to 5.10.4 and tethering started working immediately.

From [Check and Update Ubuntu Kernel Version on Ubuntu 20.04 – Linux Hint](https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/):

> 1. The Mainline tool is not available in official Ubuntu repositories, so we will need to manually add its PPA to the sources.list file in our system. Use the apt-add-repository command for this purpose:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:cappelikan/ppa
>    ```
> 2. Once you have added the mainline repository, the following step is to update the system’s repository index:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    ```
> 3. Next, install the Mainline tool with this command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install mainline
>    ```
>
>    The system might ask for confirmation by providing you with a **Y/N** option. Hit **Y** to continue, after which the Mainline tool will be installed on your system.
> 4. Launch the mainline tool from the Ubuntu search bar as follows:
>
>    [image]
> 5. When the Mainline tool is launched, you will see the following installer window with a list of new and available kernel versions. You may **install** a new version by selecting the version from the list and clicking the Install button on the bar to the right.
>
>    [image]
>
>    After this step, the following Authentication dialog will appear. Enter the super user password and click the **Authenticate** button.
>
> The installation of the selected kernel version will begin, and you will be able to see the installation process in a new window.
>
> Now, reboot your system and verify the new kernel version:
>
> ```
> uname -r
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had this USB tethering problem with IOS 14.4. with Ubuntu 20.04 but after updating IOS 14.4.2. the problem was fixed without any additional tricks !!