# How do I set up internet usb Tethering with an iPhone in ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: usb, 22.04, iphone, tether

I upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 to 22.04.

In ubuntu 16.04 I would just plug in my phone to charge, and I could tether internet very easily. The phone just asks for the pin and it worked.

In ubuntu 22.04, I can't make it work.

I have installed: ipheth-utils, libimobiledevice-dev and libimobiledevice-utils following these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-dev
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils
```

which I found on this tutorial,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hGx8JeyGKtk

I also tried to unpair the device and pair it again with

```
me@mycomputer:~$ idevicepair unpair
No device found.
me@mycomputer:~$ idevicepair pair
No device found.
```

Also, there is a solution here

[tethering iphone 6s and ubuntu 20.04 - not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291983/tethering-iphone-6s-and-ubuntu-20-04-not-working)

saying that one has to upgrade the kernel. Is there a way to avoid upgrading the kernel?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that with `ifuse` and a few step, first connect your iPhone to your computer via USB and ensure that "Personal Hotspot" is enabled then open a terminal and enter `idevice_id -l`  if your iPhone is recognized you should see its unique identifier (UDID) listed in the output, then you have to check if `usbmuxd` is running `sudo systemctl status usbmuxd` if not do

```
sudo systemctl start usbmuxd
sudo systemctl enable usbmuxd
```

then restart `NetworkManager` `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`

Now in your Ubuntu -> Setting -> Network you should have a new wired connection, just click connect to enable usb tethering. if that not work you should try a kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Saxtheowl is correct. For me, I also needed to reboot the computer. After that, once the iPhone was connected and in hot spot mode, Pop_OS! (Ubuntu flavor) immediately identified a USB connection and I was immediately connected.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a version of Kubuntu (KDE). For whatever reason, the "Connect automatically with priority" was set to -100 for the wired connection (iphone USB). Following the advice from Saxtheowl, and setting the priority to 0 worked for me.

[image]