Any way to connect to internet on unsupported network card?
Recently I have been wanting to install Ubuntu onto an SSD in enclosure, (Basically a portable mini system, recognized as a USB) whenever I boot into the Ubuntu installer from flash drive, it gives no option to connect to internet.
I did some studying and found that my network card is not supported. Is there any driver/tool I can download to make my card supported?
Here are my laptop's specs:

Model: Asus Vivobook 14 x1404ZA
Netword Card: MediaTek Wi-Fi 6E MT7902 Wireless LAN Card
Processor: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1215U 1.20 GHz
System Type: 64 Bit
Ram: 16gb
Storage: Crucial 500gb P3 Plus M.2 SSD
Version: Windows 11 Pro


If the card is unsupported, then no you can't.  You will need to get a dongle or wifi card/adapter that works with Linux.  There are dozens of small USB wifi adapters that work with Linux out there.

@ThomasWard Thanks! How expensive are those? I am on a tight budget...

If you have a smartphone, many of them do USB tethering these days, including sharing the network connection from WiFi

@muru Do you have to have your iPhone connected to the laptop the whole time whenever using Wifi?

If you go for USB tethering, yes, the phone needs to be connected to the laptop... but since you mention iPhones, it seems you need additional software with those: https://askubuntu.com/q/1461639, so it's probably not an option for you.

Use USB tethering with your phone if it supports it.  If not, you can get a cheap Wifi-N dongle for around US$20-US$30 depending on your location etc.
