# Tethering iPhone iOS 15.8 to Ubuntu 20.04 - not working

Tags: 20.04, iphone, tethering

With regard to [tethering iphone 6s and ubuntu 20.04 - not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291983/tethering-iphone-6s-and-ubuntu-20-04-not-working) I'm now up to the current kernel version 5.15.0-91 in Ubuntu 20.04 and tethering is NOT working. I had it working until I updated the iPhone to iOS 15.8, which appears to have caused the tethering to stop working.

https://github.com/potato1992/Iphone_usb_tethering_fix was a great workaround, but is no longer current.

I'm wondering how many other people are experiencing this particular problem.

Has anybody gotten this to work on the current kernel and current iOS, and if so, how?

Comment: See https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/1038 The USB packets to setup tethering have been broken since iOS 14, so I do  not have any false hopes of this issue going anywhere soon.